# How do I colour a row in Excel using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large excel sheet that has a few cells coloured green within a column. How can I identify the green cell and subsequently turn the entire row into the same background colour?

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(i, 4).Value <> Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(i, 6).Value Then
        Cells(i, 1).EnitreRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 255
    ElseIf Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(i, 4).Value = Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(i, 6).Value Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 5296274
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: **(1)** You use `Worksheets(...)` in your condition but then format the rows of the Active sheet. **(2)** Your code doesn't find green cells. It looks for values.  **(3)** Why are you comparing column 4 and 6? **(4)** your elseif-condition makes no sense and can be removed **(5)** What makes you think that the green the OP is talking about is the magic number 5296274?